# "Cannot Synthesize" -- Why is this class not ready to be declared "@Model" for use with SwiftData?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios17, swift-data

I am trying to convert the [Landmarks app](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views) to SwiftData... why isn't this class conforming to codable/decodable?  It won't compile but the messages are non-specific:

"Type 'Landmark' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'"
"Type 'Landmark' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'"

and

In expansion of macro 'Model' here:
"Cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'any SwiftData.BackingData' does not conform to 'Decodable'"

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Landmark: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var park: String
    var state: String
    var dezcription: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
    var isFeatured: Bool
    
    var category: Category
    private var coordinates: Coordinates
    private var imageName: String
    
    init(id:Int = Int.random(in: 2000...Int.max), name:String = "", park: String = "", state:String = "", dezcription: String = "", isFavorite: Bool = false, isFeatured:Bool = false, category: Category = Category.mountains, coordinates: Coordinates = Coordinates(latitude: 0, longitude: 0), imageName:String = "umbagog") {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.park = park
        self.state = state
        self.dezcription = dezcription
        self.isFavorite = isFavorite
        self.isFeatured = isFeatured
        self.category = category
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.imageName = imageName
        
    }

    
    enum Category: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
        case lakes = "Lakes"
        case rivers = "Rivers"
        case mountains = "Mountains"
    }

    var image: Image {
        Image(imageName)
    }
    
    
    var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: coordinates.latitude,
            longitude: coordinates.longitude)
    }

    struct Coordinates: Hashable, Codable {
        var latitude: Double
        var longitude: Double
    }
}
```

PS - I know that the design of this (the random int id... the default location of 0,0) are bad... but that's not the point of the question.

I've tried:

- Commenting out/isolating potentially problematic types
- Making sure everything is codable
- Including all vars in the initializer
- Reading the dos and donts of declaring a @Model class
- Making the Image var @Transient (although it is computed anyway so that should not be necessary)
- Moving the Coordinates struct and Category enum higher in scope (out of this class)
- Adding a "real" UUID variable that actually is guaranteed unique

Comment: Note that `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is not `Codable`.

Comment: You ah e to manually conform

Comment: Since this had nothing to do with Codable maybe you should remove the question completely.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sorry, this is a case where I made a false assumption in my question — That this class needs to be codable.

The reason the class was marked Codable was because that was the way it was in the original Landmarks app and I didnt think to change it.

What I didn't realize is that a class marked with @Model does not require any explicit protocols, and in fact should not be marked codable unless one plans on doing some serious surgery as in Sweeper's answer.

If I simply remove the Codable protocol (and can also remove all other protocols safely), it works.

I enterpreted the error message as a Swiftdata error when it is just a “normal” error saying “this class is not codable [because of Swiftdata macro]”

So the other previous answers are appreciated and valid if anyone out there actually has a class they need to be a swift data model *and* codable, but in my case it was just a false assumption.

One could say that this renders the question invalid, but that is hindsight and I think this the answer to my question, and the information will be valuable to people with the same misunderstanding.

Comment: Simply removing the Codable protocol to `Landmark` model is not the answer. 
You **should not have** `var image: Image {Image(imageName)}` in your model, 
and most likely you should also have `func locationCoordinate()`.

Comment: They are computed properties so they are treated as transient and their type doesnt matter.  I tested that it works. Thankyou though.

Comment: my point is `Image` is a `View` and should not be declared in a "normal" class, it is only for use in other `Views`. It may well work for you now but it may give you problems later.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Really? I thought `Image` and `Color` aren’t *just* views. They are also the SwiftUI counterpart of `UIImage`/`NSImage` and `UIColor`/`NSColor`. If you are writing a multi platform app, would you not use these types instead of using a whole bunch of `canImport(…)` checks?

Comment: This is not how I interpret the docs, [Image](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image)
 "Use an Image instance when you want to add images to your SwiftUI app. You can create images from many sources:
 ...  Instances of platform-specific image types, like `UIImage` and `NSImage`."

Comment: **I stand corrected**, it seems you can have `Views` declared inside a class, and use them in views.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is that the synthesis of the `Codable` implementation happens *after* the macros have expanded.

After the macros have expanded, all the properties you declared become computed properties, and the macros add an additional `_$backingData` property, as well as an underscored-prefixed version of each property you declared, of type `_SwiftDataNoType` (just an empty struct, acting as a placeholder), among other things.

Basically, `@Model` turns this:

```
class Foo {
    var foo: Int
    var bar: String
}
```

into:

```
class Foo: PersisrentModel {
    var foo: Int { get { ... } set { ... } }
    var bar: String { get { ... } set { ... } }
    private var _foo: _SwiftDataNoType
    private var _bar: _SwiftDataNoType

    private var _$backingData: any SwiftData.BackingData<Foo>
}
```

No wonder the `Codable` synthesis fails!

I recommend checking out the actual code that it generates (the above is only a simplified version) with Xcode's "Inline Macro" and "Expand Macro" context menu items.

You can conform to `Codable` manually, like [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-make-swiftdata-models-conform-to-codable) shows. See also [workingdog's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77505578/5133585).

Alternatively, try writing a macro that generates a `Codable` implementation. Your macro would receive the same syntax tree as `@Model`, so you will have access to the class' members before the macro expansion. You'd use it like this:

```
@Model
@CodableModel
final class Landmark: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    ...
}
```

Here is a rough sketch of such a `CodableModel`:

```
@attached(member, names: named(init(from:)), named(encode(to:)), named(CodingKeys))
@attached(extension, conformances: Codable)
public macro CodableModel() = #externalMacro(module: "...", type: "CodableModel")

// ...

public struct CodableModel: MemberMacro, ExtensionMacro {
    public static func expansion(
      of node: AttributeSyntax,
      providingMembersOf declaration: some DeclGroupSyntax,
      in context: some MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        var properties = [(type: TypeSyntax, name: TokenSyntax)]()
        let members = declaration.memberBlock.members
        for member in members {
            guard let propertyDecl = member.decl.as(VariableDeclSyntax.self) else { continue }
            guard propertyDecl.bindingSpecifier.text == "var" else { continue } // ignore lets
            guard let binding = propertyDecl.bindings.first else { continue }
            guard binding.accessorBlock == nil else { continue } // ignore computed properties
            guard let type = binding.typeAnnotation?.type else { continue }
            guard let name = binding.pattern.as(IdentifierPatternSyntax.self)?.identifier else { continue }
            properties.append((type, name))
        }
        let codingKeys = try EnumDeclSyntax("enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey") {
            for (_, name) in properties {
                "case \(name)"
            }
        }
        
        let initialiser = try InitializerDeclSyntax("init(from decoder: Decoder) throws") {
            "let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)"
            for (type, name) in properties {
                "\(name) = try container.decode(\(type).self, forKey: .\(name))"
                // TODO: use decodeIfPresent if the type is optional
            }
        }
        
        let encodeMethod = try FunctionDeclSyntax("func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws") {
            "var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)"
            for (_, name) in properties {
                "try container.encode(\(name), forKey: .\(name))"
            }
        }
        
        return [
            DeclSyntax(codingKeys),
            DeclSyntax(initialiser),
            DeclSyntax(encodeMethod),
        ]
    }
    
    public static func expansion(
        of node: AttributeSyntax,
        attachedTo declaration: some DeclGroupSyntax,
        providingExtensionsOf type: some TypeSyntaxProtocol,
        conformingTo protocols: [TypeSyntax],
        in context: some MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [ExtensionDeclSyntax] {
        [try ExtensionDeclSyntax("extension \(type): Codable") {}]
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach of using a specific `public init(from decoder: Decoder)` and
`public func encode(to encoder: Encoder)` to make your `Landmark` Codable.

Note you cannot have `var image: Image`, Image is a View and should not be part of your model.
Similarly, `var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {...}` is not Codable, use a function
instead, as shown in the example code.

```
@Model
final class Landmark: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var park: String
    var state: String
    var dezcription: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
    var isFeatured: Bool
    
    var category: Category
    private var coordinates: Coordinates
    private var imageName: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case id, name, park, state, dezcription, isFavorite, isFeatured
        case category, coordinates, imageName
    }
    
    init(id:Int = Int.random(in: 2000...Int.max), name:String = "", park: String = "", state:String = "", dezcription: String = "", isFavorite: Bool = false, isFeatured:Bool = false, category: Category = Category.mountains, coordinates: Coordinates = Coordinates(latitude: 0, longitude: 0), imageName:String = "umbagog") {
        
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.park = park
        self.state = state
        self.dezcription = dezcription
        self.isFavorite = isFavorite
        self.isFeatured = isFeatured
        self.category = category
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.imageName = imageName
    }
    
    enum Category: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
        case lakes = "Lakes"
        case rivers = "Rivers"
        case mountains = "Mountains"
    }
    
    //    var image: Image {
    //        Image(imageName) // <--- should NOT be here, Image is a View
    //    }
    
    // not Codable, use a function
    //    var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    //        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
    //            latitude: coordinates.latitude,
    //            longitude: coordinates.longitude)
    //    }
    
    func locationCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: coordinates.latitude,
            longitude: coordinates.longitude)
    }
    
    struct Coordinates: Hashable, Codable {
        var latitude: Double
        var longitude: Double
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        park = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .park)
        state = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .state)
        dezcription = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .dezcription)
        isFavorite = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isFavorite)
        isFeatured = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isFeatured)
        category = try container.decode(Category.self, forKey: .category)
        coordinates = try container.decode(Coordinates.self, forKey: .coordinates)
        imageName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .imageName)
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(park, forKey: .park)
        try container.encode(state, forKey: .state)
        try container.encode(dezcription, forKey: .dezcription)
        try container.encode(isFavorite, forKey: .isFavorite)
        try container.encode(isFeatured, forKey: .isFeatured)
        try container.encode(category, forKey: .category)
        try container.encode(coordinates, forKey: .coordinates)
        try container.encode(imageName, forKey: .imageName)
    }
    
}
```